# Why kotlinx.datetime.LocalDate specify like String in Avro schema?

Tags: kotlin, serialization, avro

I create Avro schema from koltin code. I Use [avro4k](https://github.com/avro-kotlin/avro4k) for generation schema. Avro4k [kotlinx-serialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html) for generate avro-schema.

I have date field - birthday. In my koltin code it is `val LocalDate birthday`.

Problem: If i use `java.time.LocalDate` kotlinx-serialization warning `Serializer has not been found for type 'LocalDate?'`.
If i use `kotlinx.datetime.LocalDate` i see in schema `{"name" : "birthday", "type" : "string" }`. But i expect `{"type": "int", "logicalType": "date"}` like in [davro documetation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/spec.html#Date)

What is the correct way to specify the date field in kotlin code for correct type in schema ?